# Diawi .ipa file installed in iPhone but doesn't install in iPad air

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I had build .ipa and uploaded it to diawi to test on iPhone and iPadair. ipa is successfully installed in iPhone but doesn't install in iPad air. Even it doesn't show any error. Nothing happen after click on Install application through diawi url.

Comment: Provisioning profile !!

Comment: Yes i add a provisioning profile. ipa installed successfully in iPhone but doesn't installed in iPad air.

Comment: add the iPad air to the provisioning profile and sign again